# Does vprintf thread safe in c language?

Tags: c, linux, printf

I am writing one application using on library which is using vprintf to print some information. Same way I am using vprintf to my application.

In this scenario vprintf is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could always provide more information in regards with just a mere

> In this scenario vprintf is not working

Anyways, `vprintf()` is a thread-safe function but it has a limitation that a read immediately following a write or a write immediately following a read there must be a flush work be done. May be flushing it could solve the problem for you.

For `vprintf()` the `arg_ptr` of the type `va_list` points to a list of arguments, so initialing the arguments by `va_start()` for each call of `vprintf()` should resolve the issue. Also, you can control the increment of `ar_ptr` after each `vprintf()` call by means of a `va_end()`